# qooxdoo: POST Method without showing parameter in URL

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

My Qooxdoo apps use POST Method. But always got error 414 Request-URI Too Large. i was check it and know that URL Lenght is about 4018 characters. And most if them is parameter.

How to POST Method whithout showing parameter in URL?

Thank you

Comment: POST parameters are _not_ part of the URL. If your URL gets that large, then most likely you are _not_ using POST, but GET.

Comment: Thank you...
but as I know, in Qooxdoo all JSON parameter will displayed at URL by default, eventhough use POST method. so i ask about the way to set it off.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.. it's Fixed.

By default qooxdoo displayed all parameters at URL. To set it off, just add at third element of setParameter's Method to =true, cause by default it was set false.

example: req.setParameter(vId, value, true);

Thank you...